# При изменении времени в dataframe произвести некоторые операции

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Сталкиваюсь с проблемой такого плана. Открываю **dataframe** ([тут закинул пример файла](http://file.sampo.ru/7vd2df/)) `df = pd.read_csv('temp.csv')` и в нем есть время и дата в столбце **datetime**. Если открыть в экселе то время будет как **PM и AM**. Так вот, в файле оказалась неправильная дата по дням. Решение такое - при переходе от **AM к PM**, в соседнем столбце `df['triger'] = 0` ставим значение 1 (в данном случае это с 2:55 по 20:47) - это соответствует переходу на новый день, вполне достаточно.

Как это правильно сделать?

```
id. Ac. datetime

44  100 8/18/2021 2:51
45  100 8/18/2021 2:53
46  100 8/18/2021 2:55
47  200 8/18/2021 20:47
48  100 8/18/2021 20:52
49  100 8/18/2021 20:53
```

Получаем:

```
id. Ac. datetime

44  100 8/18/2021 2:51    0 
45  100 8/18/2021 2:53    0 
46  100 8/18/2021 2:55    0 
47  200 8/18/2021 20:47   1 
48  100 8/18/2021 20:52   0 
49  100 8/18/2021 20:53   0
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно. что в файле оказалось неправильным? какой AM/PM для 20:47, вообще?

Comment: Где "он там есть"? я не вижу в исходных данных никаких PM.

Comment: Эксель просто показывает время в формате, который был установлен(выбран экселем) при конвертации. Непонятно суть вашего вопроса. Пожалуйста приведите пример ошибочной даты --->правильной даты. С чего вы решили флаг 1 поднять именно в этом месте?

Comment: а вот в 131 строке сразу идет вечер 23 августа. То есть за 22 число данных нет...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если только хотите знак в переходе, предлагаю следующее:

```
df['datetime_1']=df['datetime'].shift()
df['trigger']=df.apply(lambda x:1 if x['datetime_1'].hour<12 and x['datetime'].hour>=12 else 0, axis=1)
```

Comment: Абсолютно правильный ответ, спасибо